# Can app created under iOS Developer's account be distributed in iOS Developer Enterprise account?

Tags: ios, software-distribution, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH31-SW1

and

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html

My question is:

I have an iOS app with a development provisioning profile created under a iOS developer account.

Is it possible for my iOS app to be distributed via In-House Distribution method in an enterprise which has purchased the iOS Developer Enterprise program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to re-build and archive that app with that enterprise's license and reissue it.

Comment: When you say re-build, does it mean that I have to re-build the app with the signed certificate generated using the iOS Developer Enterprise program?